# Error when syncing Git submodules while compiling PyTorch on cluster

Tags: git, pytorch, compiler-errors

[image: error message]

I used `git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git && cd pytorch` to clone PyTorch. When I tried to use `git submodule sync && git submodule update --init –recursive` before compiling PyTorch on my cluster, it returns an error.

What's wrong with it?